# Discord.js Delete Single Message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am currently working on creating a Discord bot using [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/), and I want to have a command that you can tell it `||say Hello` or something and it will delete your comment, then say what you told it to.

My current code is

```
client.on('message', message => {
   if (message.content.startsWith("||say ")) {
      message.delete(1000); //Supposed to delete message
      message.channel.send(message.content.slice(5, message.content.length));
   }
});
```

But this is not working.

Comment: What part of it doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It turns out that I had the correct code, but my bot had to have moderator permissions.

Answer (score 2):

```
client.on('message', message => {
   if (message.content.startsWith("||say ")) {

      let input = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ") // Removes the prefix

      message.delete() // Deletes the message
      message.channel.send(input))//.then(msg=>msg.delete({timeout:"5000"}) <- if you want delete it with delay and sends the finished text
   }
});
```