# Delete invocator message after bot's answer

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I recently started creating a discord bot for fun, and I am trying to delete invocator message, but in vain.

I search for "tips" and i found this topic ([Discord.js Delete Single Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395255/discord-js-delete-single-message#)). So I used his code, it works well, until a got a console error which is:

```
(node:8012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at item.request.gen.end (D:\Windows\Documents\discord\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:85:15)
    at then (D:\Windows\Documents\discord\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:8012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:8012) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here is my delete command:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        message.delete()
            .then(msg => console.log(`Deleted message from ${msg.author.username}`))
            .catch(console.error);
    }
```

I don't know what is causing this because I don't use any `async`

(my message event: `client.on('message', message => {`)

Thanks

Comment: `.delete()` returns a promise and so is likely asynchronous. But I'm not sure that it's directly related to the error you're seeing.

Comment: are you sure your bot has the permission to delete the message. Also, what do you mean by 'it works well, until a got a console error which is'? Does it worked then stop deleted message, or does the code work until this line?

Comment: @JackRed Yes my bot got all permissions, And by "'it works well, until a got a console error which is" I wanted to say that, the message is correctly deleted, the bot still works everything is good except the console.

Comment: are you sure the problem concern this line? because the promise seems correctly handled from my point of view

Comment: It only happen when the message is delete, i will try without.


EDIT: I tried without the delete "command" and, [it just works](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/009/287/2e2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found how to solve the problem. I just have to add a timeout to the message.delete()

So the codes should looks like this:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        message.delete(1000)
            .then(msg => console.log(`Deleted message from ${msg.author.username}`))
            .catch(console.error);
    }
```

Thanks for the help.